Running Spark within SpringBoot and getting logging error
i have configured a spark application to be run within SpringBoot which will convert the csv file into parquet file.
pom.xml is as
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>performa-duckdb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- MyBatis Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DuckDB JDBC Driver Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.duckdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>duckdb_jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spark dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Log4j dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hadoop common for Parquet support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.parquet</groupId>
            <artifactId>parquet-avro</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

The bean doing conversion is as :
    package parquetGenerator.service;

    import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import java.nio.file.Paths;

@Component
public class CsvTOParquetService {

    private final SparkSession sparkSession;

    public CsvTOParquetService() {
        this.sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("CSV to Parquet Conversion")
                .config("spark.master", "local")
                .getOrCreate();
    }

    public void convertCsvToParquet(String csvFilePath, String parquetFilePath) {

        // Resolve relative paths
        String csvFileAbsPath = Paths.get(csvFilePath).toAbsolutePath().toString();
        String parquetFileAbsPath = Paths.get(parquetFilePath).toAbsolutePath().toString();


        // Read the CSV file
        Dataset<Row> csvData = sparkSession.read()
                .format("csv")
                .option("header", "true") // Assuming CSV file has a header
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .load(csvFileAbsPath);

        // Write the data to a Parquet file
        csvData.write()
                .format("parquet")
                .save(parquetFileAbsPath);
    }
}

When running it via spring boot i am getting following logging error
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger cannot be cast to class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger (org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger and org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.initializeLogging(Logging.scala:130) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:115) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]
at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.initializeLogIfNecessary$(Logging.scala:109) ~[spark-core_2.12-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1]

I have even excluded the logging dependencies but still getting the same error.
Any leads what is missing here

Your pom.xml is generally set up well, but the error suggests there's still a logging configuration issue. its possible that  Spark libraries may still bring other conflicting logging dependencies indirectly, also ensure all Log4j2-related dependencies (log4j-core, log4j-slf4j-impl, etc.) are the same version.
Run the following to verify the classpath for conflicting logging dependencies: mvn dependency:tree
Other thing is to make sure all Log4j2 dependencies use the same version. Update log4j-slf4j-impl to match the version of spring-boot-starter-log4j2
